# Is there a better way to get the nth item in a list?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

The following two expressions are equivalent:

```
(third (list 1 2 3 4))

(first (nthcdr 2 (list 1 2 3 4)))
```

However, using "third," "fourth," "fifth," etc. isn't always practical and `(first (nthcdr n list))` seems a little verbose. Is there a way to say something like `(item 2 (list 1 2 3 4))` to get the nth item in a list?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
(nth 3 (list 1 2 3 4))
```

returns 4th item  (zero based!)

According to [the HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Front/index.htm):

> ### *Accessor* [**NTH**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_nth.htm)
>
> **Description:**
>
> **nth** locates the *n*th element of *list*, where the *car* of the *list* is the “zeroth” element. Specifically,
>
> ```
> (nth n list) ==  (car (nthcdr n list))
> ```
>
> **Examples:**
>
> ```
> (nth 0 '(foo bar baz)) =>  FOO
> (nth 1 '(foo bar baz)) =>  BAR
> (nth 3 '(foo bar baz)) =>  NIL
> (setq 0-to-3 (list 0 1 2 3)) =>  (0 1 2 3)
> (setf (nth 2 0-to-3) "two") =>  "two"
> 0-to-3 =>  (0 1 "two" 3)
> ```

Answer (score 18):

[NTH](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_nth.htm) works for lists.

[ELT](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_elt.htm#elt) works for sequences. Sequences are lists and all kinds of one-dimensional arrays (vector, string, ...).

This means that ELT is the more general accessor, which not only works with lists, but also with one-dimensional arrays.