# Get list element by position

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to give a number and return the element of this position.
List  *lab* = `(R K K K K)` and I want to know if something like this `(position 1 lab)` exists on lisp. Like in C `return lab[1]`.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288292/get-index-of-list-within-list-in-lisp

Comment: No it's not maybe I wasn't clear. I want to give a number and the return value will be the element of this position like `return lab[0]`

Comment: In Common Lisp is  it `(nth index list)`, with index starting from 0.

Comment: That's it, you can answer it if you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a better way to get the nth item in a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267288/is-there-a-better-way-to-get-the-nth-item-in-a-list)

Comment: Might be worth noting that all of these accessors take time proportional to n: writing code as if they didn't is one of the causes of the 'Lisp is slow' myth.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Common Lisp the operator that gets the n-th element of a list is called `nth` (see the [manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_nth.htm#nth)):

```
(nth 2 '(a b c d))  ; returns C
```

A related operator is `nthcdr` that returns the rest of the list starting from the n-th element:

```
(nthcdr 2 '(a b c d)) ; returns (C D)
```

Answer (score 5):

For an operator that works on vectors *and* proper lists, see [`elt`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_elt.htm).

```
(let ((list (list 'a 'b 'c 'd)))
       (prog1 list
         (setf (elt list 1) 1)))
=> (A 1 C D)
```